# jquery show div only on first hover

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement, hover, fade

I'm trying to create a div with the class 'popup' which will fade in for five seconds and then fade out when 'left' is hovered on, but only on the first time of hovering. This is my code so far…

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
if (i == 1) {
    $('.left').hover(function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
    }, 
    function() {
        $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);  
    });
    i++; 
}; 
});
```

Comment: Use one. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @LarryBattle. You're right but some people like doing it the hard way. read the answers below...

Comment: @gdoron, some people like to know to do something with multiple ways. In case one of them doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.left').one('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
})
.one('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);  
});
```

Comment: This looks like the most elegant answer. It's not currently working on my site, though… [link](http://alpha.may-ninth.co.uk/work/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to apply all .left elements once, you can use it's .data() property like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.left').hover(function() {
        if ($(this).hasData("hovered_once")==false) {
            $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
            $(this).data("hovered_once")=="yes";
        }
    }, 
    function() {
        $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);  
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow. too much code. `one` does it for you out of the box(in more efficient way). Read my answer.

Comment: Yes `one` is suitable for this too. But I like using `.data` :)

Comment: You know that the handler keeps be there, If you used `unbind` o.k., but your code isn't the best practice at all. :(

Comment: Yea, but when it comes to do different stuff after the first one, this is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way. here is sample code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i=1;
  $('.left').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
             if(i<2)
             {
              $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
                 i++;
             }
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);  
        }
    });

});​
```

Sample Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/mediasoftpro/ZtWru/7/